# Display First Tier Price as default Price

Tags: magento

I am working on a project to display the first Tier Price as the default Price for a `Magento` website. Following is what I have done so far:

1. edited the `price.phtml` file
2. replaced

   $_product = $this->getProduct();

with

```
$_product = $this->getTierPrice($quantity);
```

On line 44

I tested this out and this isn't working the way I expected. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you tell us what your code does do and what you expected it to do? I assume $quantity has a value of 1. What does `$_product->getPrice();` return?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have tiered pricing setup for my products. I want the same final tiered price that shows on the checkout/cart page to show on the product view page. $quantity 1 will be equaled to the first tier. Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, just to check at the start, your code is like this, yes?:

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();              //$this is Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
$price = $_product->getTierPrice($quantity);  //$_product is Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
```

So with the variable `$_product` representing the actual product model, can you tell us what value is returned from these function calls:

```
$dummyPrice = $this->getTierPrice($quantity);
$dummyPrice = $this->getTierPrice(1);
$dummyPrice = $this->getTierPrice(); //should return an array of the tiers
$dummyPrice = $this->getFormatedTierPrice(1);
$dummyPrice = $this->getFormatedTierPrice();//should return an array of the tiers
```

Comment: Correct, the start of the code looks like the first 2 lines. The result should be whatever the first tier price is. for example:

Magento Admin Tier Price:
Website | Group | Quantity | Price
site.com  gname1     1          $100.00
site.com  gname2     5          $90.00

front end price of site should be $100.

I actually found an alternative fix to my issue. I figured this out about 20 minutes ago. You can close this one out if you'd like. Thanks for your time Malachy!

Comment: You can publish an answer to your own question to help others who search for this issue.

Comment: The code that I initially had in place worked properly. I didn't realize that I needed to use group pricing in conjunction with tier pricing.

Thanks for taking the time to help out with this Malachy!